# Validation for null values

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm writing code in Google Apps Scipt editor to export data from Google Sheets to Google Firebase. Right now, I have to hardcode the exact number of rows of data I have. How can I edit my code to continue go through the Google Sheet until it comes across an empty row?

```
//Create a menu item for 'Export to Firestore'
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu(' Firebase').addItem('Export to Firestore', 'main').addToUi();
}

function main() {
  //Get the active spreadsheet and its name for the collection name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  
  //Get the first row as object properties
  // ['Author', 'ISBN', 'Category', 'Title']
  var properties = getProperties(sheet);
  
  //Get the next 4 rows as records
  //[ ['Hansley Ford', '34787426409', 'Drama', 'Grim Peeks'], ..., ...]
  var records =  getRecords(sheet);
  
  //Export to Firestore
  var firestore = FirestoreApp.getFirestore('','','');
  
   
  exportToFirestore(firestore, sheetName, properties, records);
}
function exportToFirestore(firestore, collectionName, properties, records) {
  records.map(function(record) {
    //record: ['Hansley Ford', '34787426409', 'Drama', 'Grim Peeks']
    //props: ['Author', 'ISBN', 'Category', 'Title']
    var data = {};
    properties.forEach(function(prop,i) { data[prop] = record[i]; });
    return data;
  }).forEach(function(data) {
    firestore.createDocument(collectionName, data);
  });
}

function getProperties(sheet) {
  return sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 4).getValues()[0]; //['Author', 'ISBN', 'Category', 'Title']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Class Sheet `getDataRange()` to get the data range (from the top-left cell to the bottom-right cell of the last row and last column having a value).  Then you could use Class Range `getValues()` to get the range values and you could use values.length to know how many rows has this range or you could use Class Range `getLastRow()`

Also you could use Class Sheet `getLastRow()` to get the last row.

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet